# How to check missing values in each row of dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a dataframe with 100's of columns and millions of rows and would like to check the missing values in each row of dataframe.

Code :

```
df.isna().sum()
```

Currently, i'm analzing with above code which helps me with missing values in each column.
How we can get the missing values w.r.t each row.

Also, distribution plot of [column of rows] vs [number of missing values].

Comment: Hey, first you should use df.isna().mean() to see the % of missing data instead of .sum()

Answer (score 1):

> How we can get the missing values w.r.t each row.

You can try `sum` on columns

```py
df.isna().sum(axis=1)
```

> distribution plot of [column of rows] vs [number of missing values].

If you mean number of missing values in each columns, `df.isna().sum()` already gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in a first time to do :

```
df_nan=pd.DataFrame(df.isna().mean().reset_index()).rename(columns={"index": "columns", 0: "nan_pourcentage"}).sort_values(by='nan_pourcentage',ascending=False)
```

Just so you can you understand which columns has the most or the less NaN, and you can plot it

You can know the % total of Nan in your dataframe using : `df.isna().mean().mean()`

And now if you want the % of NaN per line :

```
for index in range(len(df.index)) :
    print("Nan in row ", index , " : " ,  df.iloc[index].isna().mean())
```

Instead of using a print you can store the result in a dataframe